# ActiveSheet vs. WorkSheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011, and I have a couple Check Boxes in one sheet. I'm trying to automate them with the following code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox12_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        If .Shapes("CheckBox12").OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOn Then
           .Range("CK1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
       Else
           .Range("CK1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
       End If
   End With
End Sub
```

This code gives me the error:
    Run-time error 445 Object does not support this action.

However if remove ws and just do

```
Private Sub CheckBox12_Click()
    With ActiveSheet
         If .Shapes("CheckBox12").OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOn Then
            .Range("CK1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
         Else
            .Range("CK1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This works just fine.

What's the deal here? I know I can just use ActiveSheet, but I always like to first set it = ws because it gives the dropdown list of properties/methods as I code.

Comment: I tried the checkbox part of your code, and it's working, whether it's activesheet or worksheet. the problem seems to lie elsewhere. Note: I am working on the Windows OS.

Comment: You just declared Dim ws As Worksheet, but did not assigned it to the actual one. Quick answer to your Q: use the second code snippet. Regards,

Comment: Thanks guys. Alex I say Set ws = ActiveSheet after declaring, is that not enough?

Comment: Just a curiosity: do you have more workbooks open?

Comment: Which line gives the error? Or does it give the error before running the first line of code?

Comment: If .Shapes("CheckBox12").OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOn gives me the error. It seems that if I use ws instead of ActiveSheet, it says OLEFormat.Object doesn't have a .Value property attached to it... but it also seems to magically appear if I change to ActiveSheet. Also no I don't have other workbooks open.

Comment: Try `Dim ws As Object` See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting a compiler error rather than a run-time error.

I suspect the reason ActiveSheet works is because the compiler doesn't check it. On the other hand, ws doesn't work because the compiler is trying to parse it and actually has a false flag. So the compiler checker has an error. It is flagging an error that actually should not be an error.

[Object doesn't support this action (Error 445)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa230371(v=vs.60).aspx)

EDIT: Also try this and let me know if it works:

```
Dim ws As Object
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    ...
```

It is also worth noting that `ActiveSheet` and `Worksheet` are not the same thing. `ActiveSheet` can also include a ChartSheet; but a ChartSheet can never be a Worksheet. So maybe it's not surprising that there are differences between `With ws` and `With ActiveSheet`.

Another thing you should try is setting your object to a variable:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim chk As Object
With ws
    Set chk = .Shapes("CheckBox12").OLEFormat.Object
    If chk.Value = xlOn Then
        .Range("CK1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        .Range("CK1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
End With
```

This may remove the ws variable from the equation. Of course it would be better to dim as the correct object rather than using the generic `as Object` but I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: Should I just use On Error Resume Next then..? Seems kinda hand-wavy

Comment: No you should not use On Error Resume Next. If ActiveSheet works then I would use that whether or not you understand it. Of course you did pose the question precisely because you want to understand it.