# VBA Excel - What methods/attributes can I use with ActiveSheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have looked at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.activesheet.aspx), and also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739448/activesheet-vs-worksheet) helpful, but I would like to know exactly how ActiveSheet behaves.  Is it like a Worksheet object?  It sound like it just returns or references a Worksheet object.  Do normal Worksheet methods and properties work with it?

I have used it in code I copied from other sources, but I would like to understand what is happening under the hood.

Thanks

Bonus question: If I have a control on sheet2, then set active sheet to sheet1 in a userform, can I then set it back to sheet2 when closing the userform?  In essence, can I change the sheet below my form to display/manipulate data while the form is active?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it like a Worksheet object?

Yes `ActiveSheet` is "Like" a worksheet object but they are not the same. `ActiveSheet` can be a "**Worksheet**", "**Chart Sheet**", "**MS Excel 4.0 Macro Sheet**" or "**MS Excel 5.0 Dialog Sheet**"

And hence one should always avoid using `Activesheet` while working with worksheets. You may not be working with the sheet you think you are.

> Do normal Worksheet methods and properties work with it?

If the `ActiveSheet` is a `Worksheet` then yes. For example, the below will work for a worksheet but not for "**MS Excel 5.0 Dialog Sheet**"

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Address
```

Regarding your bonus question, yes you can set any `Worksheet` to active sheet, i.e. bring it to the front, provided that the `Worksheet` is not hidden. Else you will have to unhide it first and then activate it.

To make a worksheet active, you may use this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
```

In a nutshell, avoid using `ActiveSheet`. Work with objects instead. [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep your recommendation in mind.  It is always nice to see what some of the best practices are.