# Autocomplete / drop down box for arguments past the first full stop

Tags: excel, vba

If I am writing an argument in Excel-hosted VBA, for example

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
```

Halfway through writing the first part -- `ActiveSheet` -- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> will autocomplete that part, or I can select the available options from a dropdown list.

However- the Intellisense dropdown box and autocompletion won't work /appear for anything after the first full stop. For example I can't autocomplete the `UsedRange` property.

Is it possible to make the suggestions appear etc. past writing the first part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `ActiveSheet` in the Object Browser (press F2), you'll see that `ActiveSheet` is typed as `Object`. Therefore, Intellisense can't display any further properties specific to the `Worksheet`. The typing of `Object` makes sense, because the active sheet might be something other than a standard Excel worksheet -- e.g. a chart sheet or a dialog sheet.

Many global properties are strongly typed, e.g. `ActiveWorkbook` as `Workbook`; Intellisense will present the properties and methods just fine.

[image]

If you are certain that `ActiveSheet` when used in this code will always refer to a `Worksheet`, you could assign it to a `Worksheet` variable:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet
```

Intellisense would then give you the appropriate properties and methods of the `Worksheet` object for the strongly-typed variable:

[image]

(Theoretically, the Excel object model could have typed `ActiveSheet` as something like `Sheet`, which would have all the common members of `Worksheet`, `Chart` and `DialogSheet`. I'm not sure why this wasn't done.)

Comment: Excellent, upvoted. Nitpick: VBA *can* resolve these members (assuming no typos!), but only at run-time (that's late binding). IntelliSense, for obvious reasons, requires the data type to be known at compile-time (early binding). The solution is to declare a variable using an explicit type, and then assign our `Object` (or `Variant`) to that variable, effectively *casting* it to an early-bound data type. e.g. `Dim ws As Worksheet`, then `Set ws = ActiveSheet`, and then work with `ws`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Fixed. Is that better? NB Rubberduck caused Excel to crash three times when I was preparing these GIFs.

Comment: Helpful explanations like that would be an essential step (or even mile stone) towards understanding Intellisense and VBE in number of Excel books and *bibles* :+)